# Change icon class in "Add to cart" button

Tags: theming

I am using Drupal 7, Ubercart, and Bootstrap. The default ***Add to cart*** button looks like this:

```
<button id="edit-submit-270" class="node-add-to-cart btn btn-success form-submit" value="Add to cart" name="op" type="submit">
  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Add to cart
</button>
```

How can I change the `<span>` class  from glyphicon-plus to glyphicon-shopping-cart?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution is achieving it with simple Jquery line

```
$('span.icon.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-shopping-cart');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it another class in your template.php file, and CSS does the rest

```
/**
 * @param $variables
*/
function yourtheme_preprocess_button(&$variables) {
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'] = array();
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn';
  if (stristr($variables['element']['#value'], 'Add to cart') !== FALSE) {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-cart';
  }
}
```